# Cython and regex.h

Tags: python, regex, cython

I am relatively new to Cython, so apologies if this question seems very basic.

There is a parallelizable block of regex matching, and I'd like to run it with Cython and `nogil`. To avoid using Python objects, my plan is to import `regex.h`.

The following import segment compiles:

```
cdef extern from "regex.h" nogil:
   ctypedef struct regoff_t
   ctypedef struct regex_t
   ctypedef struct regmatch_t
   int regcomp(regex_t* preg, const char* regex, int cflags)
   int regexec(const regex_t *preg, const char *string, size_t nmatch, regmatch_t pmatch[], int eflags)

def matchPatterns(str pageContent, str regex):
   cdef set matchingPatterns = set()
   return matchingPatterns
```

But as soon as I make use of `regex_t` or any of its functions, I get the error: `contentMatchPatternCython.pyx:10:16: Variable type 'regex_t' is incomplete`

If I remove the empty `ctypedef`s, the code does not compile as `regex_t` is undefined. Obviously, I think/hope that there's a way forward without duplicating the struct definition in Cython.

I'm using Python 2.7.2 and Cython 0.22. Any pointers would be received with gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html

To directly quote the documentation:

> If the header file declares a big struct and you only want to use a
>   few members, you only need to declare the members you’re interested
>   in. Leaving the rest out doesn’t do any harm, because the C compiler
>   will use the full definition from the header file.
>
> In some cases, you might not need any of the struct’s members, in
>   which case you can just put pass in the body of the struct
>   declaration, e.g.:

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    struct A:
        pass
    # or (I've added this bit - not in the documentation directly...)
    ctypedef struct B:
        pass
```

Which of these to use depends if you're matching C code that reads `struct A {}` or `typedef struct {} B`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware about this part of the documentation. However, `regex_t` is not used by me directly - it's used by the APIs I import, so there's no option of restricting the data members list. Obviously, there is the option of manually duplicating the full definition of the structs, but that just looks cumbersome and unmaintainable. Doesn't Cython have a way of automatically importing a struct definition with all members included?

Comment: All you need to do is add the `pass` statement and it will work - you don't use the members yourself so Cython doesn't need to know about them.